# Radio button within radio button Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a radio button (Tuition Fee) and once it being click, additional radio button for options will display with text field. How come after clicking the additional button (Full tuition or Not Full tuition) it will close. So what happened? I can't type in the text field. Can anyone tell me why it closed?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.sub_list').css('display','none');
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        $('.sub_list').css('display','none');
        $('#'+this.value).css('display','block');
        console.log(this.value);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test2" name="ship_need" type="radio" value="Tuition_fee"> Tution<br>

<div id="Tuition_fee" class="sub_list">
    <ul>
        <li>Tuition Fee</li>
        <input  name="Full" type="radio" value="Full"> Full Tuition Fee <br>
        <input name="Not_Full" type="radio" value="Not_Full"> Not Full Tution Fee
    </ul>

    <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Money:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="ship_money2" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
        <label class="control-label">
            Location:
        </label>         
        <select class="form-control" name="ship_payment">
            <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
            <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
            <option value="6 Month">6 Month</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.sub_list').css('display','none');` make it to close, if you don't what to close remove it

Answer (score 0):

It's because `$('input[type=radio]').change(/* ... */)` adds the change event listener to ALL your radio buttons, even the ones within `.sub_list`

`$('input[name=ship_need]').change(/* ... */)` may be where you want to add the change event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `change` event for `input[type=radio]`, you're doing

```
$('.sub_list').css('display', 'none');     //[1]
$('#'+this.value).css('display','block');  //[2]
```

On the first radio button (with ID "test2"), the `value` is "Tuition_fee".

So `$(".sub_list")` is set to `display: none` (on `[1]`).

Then, `$("#Tuition_fee")` is set to `display: block` (on `[2]`; it's the same element, and it happens too fast, so it's not noticeable).

However, on the second time you click a radio button (for example, "Full Tuition Fee"), the value is `Full`.

So `.sub_list` is set to `display: none` again (on `[1]`).

And then `#Full` (doesn't exist) is set to `display: block` (on `[2]`). There is no element with ID "Full", and so the container`<div id="Tuition_fee" class="sub_list">` stays as `display: none`.